# OpenCv, get image information

Tags: c++, opencv

I am playing around with an open source openCv application. With the provided image sets, it works great, but when I attempt to pass it a live camera stream, or even recorded frames from that camera stream, it crashes. I assume that this is to do with the cv::Mat type, differing image channels, or some conversion that i am not doing.

The provided dataset is grey-scale, 8 bit, and so are my images.
The application expects grayscale (CV_8U).

My question is:

Given one of the (working) provided images, and one of my recorded (not working) images, what is the best way to compare them using opencv, to find out what the difference might be that is causing my crashes?

Thank you.

I have tried:

Commenting out this code (Which gave assertion errors)

```
  if(mImGray.channels()==3)
    {

            cvtColor(mImGray,mImGray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cvtColor(imGrayRight,imGrayRight,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    }
    else if(mImGray.channels()==4)
    {

            cvtColor(mImGray,mImGray,CV_BGRA2GRAY);
            cvtColor(imGrayRight,imGrayRight,CV_BGRA2GRAY);

    }
```

And replacing it with:

```
    cv::Mat TempL;
    mImGray.convertTo(TempL, CV_8U);
    cvtColor(TempL, mImGray, CV_BayerGR2BGR);
    cvtColor(mImGray, mImGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

And the program crashes with no error...

Comment: What is the error, and what is the code?

Comment: the original code looks correct, while yours does not. (CV_BayerGR2BGR looks like an artefact from code completion)

Comment: ok, thanks. That was an attempt at debayering, as the camera gives me raw image data. With the original code though, I get assertion errors on the cvtColor call. Is this because I am passing it the wrong format?

Comment: You can check if the image is empty before calling cvtColor with `mImGray.isEmpy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
if ( mImGray.depth() != CV_8U )
    mImGray.convertTo(mImGray, CV_8U);

if (mImGray.channels() == 3 )
{
   cvtColor(mImGray, mImGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
}
```

Or you can define a new Mat with create function and use that.